# Multiple child routes in React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement a router where a Route has two parallel/independent sub-routes and I wonder if this is possible with `react-router`. The image below illustrates what I want to achieve. It represents an event-editor with two components: (1) a list of events (2) an editor for one event. I think their states should both be part of the URL somehow.

[image: Illustration]

One extra constraint: `[child1]` should be aware of the state of `[child2]`, since it needs to show the item that is currently edited in a different color or so.

If this is not possible with `react-router`, how would you implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to only have the `/app/child2` route? `child2` in your sketch seems to be the owner of the `event`? Furthermore, to me, `calendar/:date` and `list/:showHistory/:filter` seems to be backend related API calls and not something that the client router should handle. If you're using a Flux arcitechture then I would reason about those as actions and not routes.

Comment: @limelights, the thing is that I also want to handle changes in child1 via the browser's back button etc. Or is this also possible in another way? I am not very familiar with Flux. I don't know what 'actions' are. I use Meteor as a backend. (https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor)

Comment: Hmm, I see `/search/` as a totally *new* child and not apart of `child1` so something to this effect `/search?q=MyMeetupGroupEvent&type=child1` (if you understand what I'm getting at) which would render `child3` and also `/list/` as an action you can take on `child1` which also would render in `child3`.

Comment: Hmm, what I meant with `/search` is actually just another way to show a list of events. Here's two illustrations of the old app I'm rewriting: http://postimg.org/image/w911n3ypn http://postimg.org/image/jpe36qaxz/

Comment: Looking at your images I still maintain that `child2` is the owner and the others are just actions you can take. However, looking at them you can distinctly see that you want to have a calendar view and a list view. So something like this in order to determine what `child2/listview/` and `child2/calendar` would be in order for your routes.

Comment: Okay. Something like that should work. Thank you. There is two issues I am still struggling with: (1) how should I go about handling the parameters for the views (listview and calendar) and (2) `child2` can also be empty, that is, no event is currently selected. Can `react-router` handle this type of parent-child relationship, where the the parent could either be `/edit/:id` or `/create` or even `/`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88914/discussion-between-limelights-and-thijs).

Answer (score -1):

Look this. By doing this you can create a parallel control of routes, without harming root.

```
/**at index.html*/
< div id="root"></div>
< div id="helper"></div>

/**at index.js*/
ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Helper />
    </BrowserRouter>
  ),
  document.getElementById('helper')
);


/**at Component Helper*/
render() {
    const location = { pathname: '/2' }
    return (<Switch location={location}>
      <Route exact path='/2' component={Welcome} />
    </Switch>);
}

const Welcome = () => <h3>welcome helper</h3>

//I'm using router V4 to switch of the routers.
```

Comment: Please give some explanation why your code might solve the problem. So, others can learn from it.